# Xcode Pinterest.h file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pinterest, lexical

So I have looked high and low for a fix for this and nothing seems to work. I have a a project that works 100%, but when I transfer it over to another mac I get the following error. Pinterest.h file not found. However this file is in fact present and makes no sense why I am getting this error. I have tried cleaning build, cleaning build folder, restarting xcode, checking build paths and I simply cannot figure out this issue. Here is an image of the error

[image: http://puu.sh/dPczl/e8329684d7.png]

and here is an image of the class that is causing the error

[image: http://puu.sh/dPd3T/c5528d487b.png] Literally any help on this would be amazing, I am using sharekit if that helps at all.

Comment: The Pinterest.h file you claim exists. Does it in fact fall inside a Pinterest subdirectory of an existing include path?

Comment: I have the Pinterest.h file in the exact same location on the HDD as my other mac, but I am not sure if its in the existing include path, how would I check

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have Pinterest.h included in the actual project? It could be that, on your second device, you forgot to include the Pinterest.h as a file inside the project itself. It might be within the directory structure, but that doesn't mean that it's included in the Xcode project.

With the limited images you provided, it's really hard to tell one way or the other. Can you provide more information/images?

Comment: Yes! what images would you need, I am pretty sure the file is included but I could be wrong, hence my confusion.
I certainly have a Pinterest.h file on my HDD in the same location as my other mac, but how do I include it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The file should appear somewhere in the directory structure on the left side of xcode. If it doesn't, you need to right click in that window and select "Add Files To <...>" (Where <...> is the name of your project). Then, add Pinterest.h. Let me know if that solves your issue.

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If so, can you mark it as answered?